# OpenCV CV_EXPORTS

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

In the matx.hpp library located in opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp
there is `struct CV_EXPORTS Matx_AddOp {};` code. can anyone help me what does it mean or what type of data is the Matx_AddOp.

Comment: You should find the define of `CV_EXPORTS`. I guess it's just attributes, and the struct is empty.

Answer (score 1):

CV_EXPORTS is a macro. It is defined in [cvdef.h](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3d141280aa05a6543e98438166aff25970e8ff8f/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h#L261).

```
# if (defined _WIN32 || defined WINCE || defined __CYGWIN__)
#   define CV_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
# elif defined __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ >= 4
#   define CV_EXPORTS __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
# endif
```

So it is not a type!! you should think the struct is more like this:

```
struct Matx_AddOp {}
```

This means, that it is an empty struct.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 2.4.13.6_2:  `types_c.h`

```
#if (defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined WINCE) && defined CVAPI_EXPORTS
#  define CV_EXPORTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define CV_EXPORTS
#endif
```